# Swap fragments dynamically at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I'm trying to implement a side drawer and the main content is being populated by fragments.
But when I swap those fragments and try to swap it back the content of both fragments overlays.

This is my code so far:

```
private void createDefaultFragment(){
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.home_content, getFragment(0))
            .commit();
}

private void swapFragment(int index){
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.home_content, getFragment(index))
            .commit();
}
```

`getFragment` returns a `Fragment` object that the user requested.

```
private Fragment getFragment(int index)
{

    String fragmentClassNames[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_drawer_fragments);
    try {
        Class<?>requestedClass = Class.forName(fragmentClassNames[index]);
        Constructor<?> constructor = requestedClass.getConstructor();
        return (Fragment)constructor.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The class names are saved as a `string-array` in the resources so the drawer is easily extensible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling `createDefaultFragment()` and `swapFragment()`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ´createDefaultFragment()´ is called in the ´ onCreate´ function and ´swapFragment´ whenever the user selects an item in the drawer's ´ListView´

Comment: What do you do when you "swap it back"? Please edit your original question with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be calling replace instead of add in createDefaultFragment.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it works too - saves me an extra function for adding a fragment :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how the fragments were created:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_searches_fragment, container);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Is wrong - you have to return the view supplied by `inlater.inflate(...)`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_searches_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Just in case somebody other has this problem ;)
(And don't forget to add `false` to the parameters of `inflate(...)`)